# Units of solubility in water?

Tags: siunitx, chemistry

I am trying to write the units for solubility of a chemical substance (`\ce{KNO_3}`) in 100g of water.

Currently, I am using:

```
\SI{}{\gram / 100 \gram \ce{H_2O}}
```

or

```
\SI{}{\gram / 100 \gram of water}
```

what I get is:

[image]

Problem: there is no space between 100g and water/H_2O.

How to include space between the two?

Comment: Your approach is quite strange. Why you not write this on more usual (standard) way? For example as `\SI{100}{\gram}~\ce{H2O}` or `\SI{100}{\gram} \ce{H2O}`? Or maybe as `\SI{100}{\gram\ce{H2O}}` (your question is no clear, sorry).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strange unit…

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\DeclareSIUnit{\solub}{\unit[per-mode=symbol]{\gram\per(\qty{100}{\gram}\,\ce{H2O}})}

\begin{document}

\qty{42}{\solub}

\end{document}
```

[image]